# Web browsers assume that my HTTP server is prepared to accept many connections

Tags: google-chrome, http, tcp

I'm developing a web server and application on a microcontroller where resources (especially RAM) are very limited. When I point Chrome or Firefox to the web page hosted by my embedded web server, it attempts to establish a total of 6 concurrent TCP connections. First it opens one and loads the main HTML, then it attempts to open 5 more for loading various resources.

My server only has resources to handle 3 concurrent connections. Currently the device is programmed to refuse further connections by sending an RST packet in response to the SYN packets. So the first 3 SYN packets get a normal SYN-ACK reply and HTTP traffic starts, the latter 3 get an RST.

Both Chrome and Firefox seem to decide that the RST responses are fatal and abandon loading certain resources.

If the device does not send these RST responses (just forgets about the SYNs), Chrome loads the page fine. But I don't like the zombie connection attempts on the client.

- Should browsers really be assuming the RST responses to connection attempts are fatal? I was under the impression that an HTTP server is allowed to close the connection at any time and the client should retry at least GET requests transparently.
- What is the best solution, practically? Keep in mind that perhaps I would like to support multiple web clients with for example 4 connections in total, and if the first client grabs all 4, there are none left for the second client.

Note that for my application there is zero benefit of having parallel connections. Why must I support so many connections just because the client thinks it will be faster? Even if I manage to support 6 now, what when the browser vendors decide to increase the default and break my application?

**EDIT** - I see the same issue with Firefox as well not just Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed modern browsers will try to use 6 connections, in some cases even 8. You have one of two options:

1. Just ACK but take your time replying
2. Use javascript to load your resources one-by-one

I am assuming here that you can't increase the concurrent capacity of the server (being a small device) or radically change the appearance of the page.

Option #2 removes most of the resources from the page and instead has JS programatically request every resource and add them to the page via the DOM. This might be a serious rework of the page.

I should also mention that you can inline images (the image bitmap is just a string in the page) so that you can prevent the (mostly) parallel fetching of images done by modern browsers.

Comment: I have solved it by keeping a queue of pending (accepted) connections (which need much less resources - essentially no memory for buffers), combined with having the server close each connection after servicing the first request. This makes sure that the queued connections do get their turn eventually.

Answer (score 1):

> I was under the impression that an HTTP server is allowed to close the connection at any time and the client should retry at least GET requests transparently.

The server is allowed to close the connection after the first response was sent, i.e. it might ignore the wish of the client to keep the connection open. The server is not allowed to close the connection within or before the first request was handled.

> What is the best solution, practically?

Don't use too much resources which need to be retrieved in separate requests. Use data-URL's and similar. Or increase your listen queue to accept more than 3 TCP connections at the same time.

Comment: I know that HTTP supports pipelining (issuing multiple requests on the same connection then waiting for all responses in sequence). Is there a way to encourage the client to do this instead of opening many connections?

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: HTTP Pipelining is something different (multiple **open** requests on the same connections). What you mean is keep alive. Modern browsers use keep alive  but they will still open multiple connections if you have much resources which need to be retrieved.